# Is there a name for the set theory usually described in analysis textbooks?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

It seems to me that in most analysis textbooks, from calculus to abstract analysis, except for AC, the set theory described there has very little to do with ZFC. You would never see anything like $2\in 5$, $2\subset 5$ or $\aleph_0=\mathbb{N}$. Is there an accepted name for this kind of set theory. "Naive" or "informal" somehow seems too dismissive given it's astounding success.

Comment: You never particularly see any of that in texts on ZFC either... In any case, it's usually just called "informal" set theory.

Comment: Not entirely facetiously: Chapter 0 set theory.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine It could easily be formalized. There is nothing hand-wavy about it these days. Or am I being, umm... naive?

Comment: "Could be formalized" is not the same as "is formalized," however. :P

Comment: The main notable ideas in set theory are things like "there is no set of all sets" and that sets can be built up from previous sets using very intuitive axioms of construction. There are some set theorists that reject the axiom of infinity but IMO they're just crazy. As far as analysis goes, the only somewhat "deep" set theory result I've ever seen used is declaring a Hamel basis for ${\mathbb R}$ as a vector space over ${\mathbb Q}$, where the Hamel basis is used to demonstrate an additive (Cauchy) function which is not continuous. (and this requires the axiom of choice)

Comment: In most of the cases we are working in ZFC. Why do you think, we don't?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine "Informal" just seems too much of a catchall. There does seem to be a wide consensus on "Chapter 0  set theory," as Brian put it somewhat facetiously. If it was formalized, what might it be called?

Comment: I think most of the above comments are missing the point: in normal mathematical practice we tend to consider a judgment like $e \in \pi$ to be ill-formed rather than having a truth value that is contingent upon how you define the real numbers. Providing foundations for mathematics that reflect this is the subject of many-sorted logic and type theory.

Comment: I think the case you mentioned is just because the particular approach used to achieve the end (i.e. properties of nature number, arithmetic, etc.) is irrelevant when we applying those things. You won't care whether {a} is contained in ordered pair (a,b) or not. Those properties, as well as $2 \in 5$ or something like that, are freak and not necessary in some degree.

Comment: @user251257 In analysis, you have $\aleph_0=|\mathbb{N}|$. In ZFC theory, I understand it's  $\aleph_0=\mathbb{N}$. Seems like it would be a very important distinction.

Comment: @DanChristensen: you know cardinals are actually equivalence classes ...

Comment: @user251257 That is the case in analysis, but is it in ZFC theory as well?

Comment: @DanChristensen: Well, in ZFC, you need to select a representative. That however doesn't differ from how we handle for example real numbers.

Comment: @user251257: so is $e \in \pi$?

Comment: @RobArthan: In which model? However, it is valid to ask for it and there is answer.

Comment: @user251257 No, the ZFC theorists here were quite adamant the other day. They say everything is a set and that $\aleph_0$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are the same sets *by definition*.

Comment: @DanChristensen: Like I said, you need to select a representative in ZFC, as cardinals are proper classes (in what ever theory which allows classes). So most  people (probably everyone) would select $\mathbb N$. That is the definition.

Comment: @user251257: you might like to look at this paper by Benecerraf on [what numbers could not be](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1240846.files/Benacerraf.pdf).

Comment: @RobArthan: Is your point that the answer depends on the model and thus isn't well posed? That is probably more a conflict between axiomatic approach or constructive approach. I do agree that if we identify all models of the reals, than we can't ask $e \in \pi$ or for the matter even $0\in 1$.

Comment: @user251257 I doubt that many analysts would accept $\aleph_0=\mathbb{N}$. They define a cardinality operator defined for every set.

Comment: My point is that single-sorted first-order set theory doesn't reflect mathematical practice, in which we have a single abstract notion of the real number system (say) rather than many conflicting representations of it.

Comment: @DanChristensen: It is more like, from a practical point of view, it is absolutely irrelevant whether I take $\aleph_0 = \mathbb N$ or only $\aleph_0 = |\mathbb N|$. Just like I do not rely on the fact that real numbers are in fact for example equivalence classes of cauchy sequences.

Comment: @RobArthan: I agree. I just disagree on OP, which makes the impression that most part of analysis happens in some kind of different set theory that is not equivalent to ZFC.

Comment: @Dan: It depends on what you mean by "by definition"; you could choose $\mathbb{N}$ to be represented by a different set than represents $\aleph_0$, as was mentioned in the thread on that topic. We just happen to use the same set for both.

Comment: And I look forward to the day where you make a post that's not about obsessing over trivial side effects of set theoretic implementations of numbers...